# Загрузка изображений в многостраничном приложении Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Возникла следующая проблема: после того, как я организовал многостраничное приложение с помощью pages в vue.config.js, у меня перестали загружаться картинки. Приложение компилируется нормально, однако в браузере обнаруживается несколько ошибок (приложу скриншот с ними). Как решить эту проблему? Пробовал по разному указывать путь и в разные папки ложить картинки, не помогло. Код файлов представлен ниже. Так же приложу скриншот со структурой проекта
Код `vue.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    'index': {
      entry: './src/pages/Home/main.js',
      template: 'public/index.html',
      title: 'Home',
      chunks: [ 'chunks-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'index' ]
    },
    'main': {
      entry: './src/pages/Main/main.js',
      template: 'public/index.html',
      title: 'Main',
      chunks: [ 'chunks-vendors', 'chunk-common', 'main' ]
    }
  }
}
```

Код `Home/main.js`:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

Код `Home/App.vue`:

```
<template>
  <nav class="navbar is-primary" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
    <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
      <a class="navbar-link is-arrowless">
        <img src="C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\web-book-vue\public\img\Strip Menu Icon.png"/>
      </a>
      <div class="is-primary navbar-dropdown is-size-4">
        <a href="" class="navbar-item"> Личный кабинет </a>
        <hr />
        <a href="" class="navbar-item"> Тестирование </a>
        <hr />
        <a href="" class="navbar-item"> Подбор интерфейса </a>
        <hr />
        <a href="" class="navbar-item"> Справка </a>
        <hr />
        <a href="" class="navbar-item"> Выход </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-end">
      <div class="navbar-item">
        <div class="buttons">
          <a @click="openRegister" class="button is-primary">
            <strong>Зарегестрироваться</strong>
          </a>
          <a @click="openLogIn" class="button is-light"> Войти </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <section class="hero is-fullheight-with-navbar">
    <div class="hero-body">
      <div class="content is-large">
        <h1>
          Автоматизированная информационная среда "Электронный гипертекстовый
          учебник с адаптивным интерфейсом
        </h1>
        <p>Вы ещё не зарегестрированы?</p>
        <button @click="openRegister" class="button is-primary is-large">
          <strong>Зарегестрироваться</strong>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <div class="modal" :class="{ 'is-active': logInIsActive }">
    <div class="modal-background"></div>
    <div class="modal-card">
      <header class="modal-card-head">
        <p class="modal-card-title has-text-centered">
          <strong>Авторизация</strong>
        </p>
        <button @click="closeLogIn" class="delete"></button>
      </header>
      <section class="modal-card-body">
        <form class="section">
          <div class="field has-text-centered is-primary">
            <img src="C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\web-book-vue\src\img\logo.jpg" alt="" width="167" />
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <label for="login" class="label">Логин</label>
            <div class="control">
              <input
                id="login"
                type="text"
                class="input"
                placeholder="Введите логин"
                required
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <label for="password" class="label">Пароль</label>
            <div class="control">
              <input
                id="password"
                type="password"
                class="input"
                placeholder="Введите пароль"
                required
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="fieled">
            <a href="main.html" class="button is-primary">Войти</a>
          </div>
        </form>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal" :class="{ 'is-active':registerIsActive }">
    <div class="modal-background"></div>
    <div class="modal-card">
      <header class="modal-card-head">
        <p class="modal-card-title has-text-centered">Зарегестрироваться</p>
        <button @click="closeRegister" class="delete"></button>
      </header>
      <section class="modal-card-body">
        <form class="section">
          <div class="field">
            <label for="email">Адрес электронной почты</label>
            <div class="control">
            <input type="email" id="email" class="input" placeholder="Введите Email" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <label for="regLogin">Логин</label>
            <div class="control">
            <input type="text" id="control" class="input" placeholder="Введите логин" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <label for="regPassword">Пароль</label>
            <div class="control">
            <input type="password" id="regPassword" class="input" placeholder="Придумайте пароль" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <label for="regConfirmPassword">Подвердите пароль</label>
            <div class="control">
            <input type="password" id="regConfirmPassword" class="input" placeholder="Подтвердите пароль" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <button class="button is-primary">Зарегестрироваться</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      logInIsActive: false,
      registerIsActive: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    openLogIn() {
      this.logInIsActive = true
    },
    closeLogIn() {
      this.logInIsActive = false
    },
    openRegister() {
      this.registerIsActive = true
    },
    closeRegister() {
      this.registerIsActive = false
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Код `Main/main.js`:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

Код `Main/App.vue`:

```
<template>
  <nav class="navbar is-primary" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
    <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
      <a class="navbar-link is-arrowless">
        <img
          src="assets\Strip Menu Icon.png"
        />
      </a>
      <div class="is-primary navbar-dropdown is-size-4">
        <a href="" class="navbar-item"> Личный кабинет </a>
        <hr />
        <a href="" class="navbar-item"> Тестирование </a>
        <hr />
        <a href="" class="navbar-item"> Подбор интерфейса </a>
        <hr />
        <a href="" class="navbar-item"> Справка </a>
        <hr />
        <a href="" class="navbar-item"> Выход </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-end">
      <div class="navbar-item">
        <div class="buttons">
          <a @click="openRegister" class="button is-primary">
            <strong>Зарегестрироваться</strong>
          </a>
          <a @click="openLogIn" class="button is-light"> Войти </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <section class="hero is-fullheight-with-navbar">
    <div class="columns">
      <aside class="column is-2">
        <div class="menu">
        <ul class="menu-list">
          <li><a href="#">Введение в C++</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
      </aside>
      <main class="column">
        Какой-то текст
      </main>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      logInIsActive: false,
      registerIsActive: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    openLogIn() {
      this.logInIsActive = true;
    },
    closeLogIn() {
      this.logInIsActive = false;
    },
    openRegister() {
      this.registerIsActive = true;
    },
    closeRegister() {
      this.registerIsActive = false;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

[image: Ошибки в браузере]

[image: Структура проекта]

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `@/assets/logo.jpg`, а не полный путь.

Comment: Пробовал, тогда вообще не компилируется приложение. Могу привести код ошибки в тексте вопроса, если надо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё оказалось очень просто. Просто надо было поместить картинки в папку `public`, либо в ней же создать отдельную папку для картинок (например, `img`), и указать путь следующим образом:

```
<img src="Strip Menu Icon.png"/>
```

или, если картинки находятся в папке `img`:

```
<img src="img/Strip Menu Icon.png"/>
```